# Using pingpong sky module in laravel 5

Tags: php, module, laravel-5, hmvc

i wonder why i'm get something like this when add pingpong sky module to project

[image: problem]

i think, i already follow all instruction in pingpong sky installation 
when i create module Auth in cmd i got **message success** 
but when i try to access Auth module in browser by this url
`http://localhost/skypp/public/auth` 
i got message error

```
FatalErrorException in Application.php line 575:
Class 'Modules\Auth\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found
```

i think some problem occur when create that module
so i tried again make new module,
but it's failed this time like in pict

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Modules\Auth\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found
```

where i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple and I don't know why the module:make command doesn't integrate it...

Please run a composer dump-autoload so that it rescans the PSR-4 folder and you should be good to go :)

Comment: already done that..but nothing changed
anyway i already try laravel 4 with creolab package and it's run smooth now :D